# What does RTLD stand for in dlopen()?

Tags: flags, dlopen

In dynamic linking loading,

the functions like `dlopen()` use the flags like **RTLD_LOCAL** and **RTLD_NOW**.
(https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

What does RTLD stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does RTLD stand for?

The **R**un**T**ime **L**oa**D**er